# How to hide issue_template folder from github repo while the issue_templates are still functional

Tags: github, repository, github-issues

i have added issue templates in my github repo but i want to hide issue template files from the public while the issue templates still work.
In simple words, i want to hide this folder(.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE) from my github repo but still want it to be functional

i tried using the .gitignore file, it ignores the folder from github repo, which does not allows the issue templates to be functional.

[Github repo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykRuz.jpg)